# A question about indeterminate $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> **Theorem.** For any field $F$, the power series ring $F[[x]]$ is a P.I.D.; in fact, the nontrivial ideals of $F[[x]]$ are of the form $(x^k)$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

**Proof**. Suppose that $I\subset F[[x]]$ a proper ideal and let $f(x)\in I\setminus\{0\}$ that has minimum order $k$. I have shown that $k$ can not be zero. Then let $k>0$. Therefore 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x)&=a_kx^k+a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+\cdots+\cdots\\
&= x^k(a_k+a_{k+1}x+a_{k+2}x^{k+2}+\cdots+).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
**Question 1.** For my book, $x\notin F[[x]]$, so how is the last passage possible?

**Question 2.** Explicitly who are they $(x^k)$?

**Question 3** If you use the convention that $1\cdot x=x$, then is it true or false that even if $x$ is a symbol I can write $x$ how $x=0+1x+0x^2+\cdots+$? And consequently consider $x$ as an element of $F[[x]]$?

Comment: Are you sure you read the definition correctly that $x\not\in F[[x]]$? I believe you are incorrect in this interpretation.

Comment: The book, David Burton, A First course in rings and ideals at the beginning of the chapter 7 specific that the indeterminant $x$ is simply a new symbol and that many authors identify the power series $0+1x+0x^2+\cdots$ with $x$, but after reiterates that he does not do it.... But in this case I belive that $x$ is a sequence....

Comment: Question 2: $(x^k)$ are the power series whose first non-zero coefficient (if any) is $a_k$, i.e., power series like $f(x)$ in your question.

Comment: Is it correct to say that $(x^k)=\{ax^k\;|\;a\in F[[x]]\}$?

Comment: On that title - it's a common mistake, but "indeterminant" is not a legitimate word in mathematical English. The word you were looking for was "indeterminate", the state of not being determined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1): By calling those ideals $(x^k)$, we are implicitly saying that there is an element of the ring named $x$, which is exactly what you think it is. Is it the same object as the $x$ that goes into the definition of the ring? Probably not, but we don't really care; we're not going to run into a context where both meanings could fit and would produce different results.

(2): The ideal $(x^k)$ is the set of multiples of $x^k$, exactly as you said. Of course, that means we're multiplying it by any power series, so in terms of coefficients we get
$$(x^k) = \left\{a_0x^k + a_1x^{k+1}+\cdots + a_nx^{k+n}+\cdots\ \mid\ a_0,a_1,\cdots\in F\right\}$$
for coefficients up to $k-1$ zero and all others unrestricted.

There's another name that goes with this structure, with one ideal that generates all others as powers of it and everything outside that ideal invertible; this is called a local ring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, If I start my discussion saying: Let $F[[x]]$( here $x$ is a symbol) the ring of the power series and I find an ideal of the type $(\tilde{x}^2)$, where $\tilde{x}\in F[[x]]$. Can I say that $F[[x]]=F[[\tilde{x}]]$?

Comment: @JackJ. *Please* just use $x$ to denote the power series with coefficients $(0,1,0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: @Christoph. Therefore the idea would be the following: even if $x$ is only a symbol, we can consider the sequece $(0,1,0,…)$ that formally can we write as $0+1\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+\cdots+$. Using the convencion for which $1\cdot x=x$, then $x=0+x+0\cdots+$, and then see $x$ as an element of $F[[x]]$. Right?

Comment: Yes , everybody does that. You just have to be careful to still consider $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ as a formal expression for the coefficient sequence $(a_0, a_1, \dots)$ and **not** an infinite sum over the elements $a_k x^k\in F[[x]]$, since there is no notion of convergence for this to even be defined.